# Connecting to scality/s3 server between docker containers

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, boto3

We are using a python based solution which shall load and store files from S3. For developing and local testing we are using a vagrant environment with docker and docker-compose. We have two docker-compose defintions - one for the assisting backend services (mongo, restheart, redis and s3) and the other one containing the python based REST API exposing solution using the backend services.

When our "front-end" docker-compose group interacts with restheart this works fine (using the name of the restheart container as server host in http calls). When we are doing the same with scality/s3 server this does not work.

The interesting part is, that we have created a test suite for using the scality/s3 server from a python test suite running on the host (windows10) over the forwarded ports through vagrant to the docker container of scality/s3 server within the docker-compose group. We used the endpoint_url localhost and it works perfect.

In the error case (when frontend web service wants to write to S3) the "frontend" service always responds with:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidURI) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Could not parse the specified URI. Check your restEndpoints configuration.
And the s3server always responds with http 400 and the message:

s3server     | {"name":"S3","clientIP":"::ffff:172.20.0.7","clientPort":49404,"httpMethod":"PUT","httpURL":"/raw-data","time":1521306054614,"req_id":"e385aae3c04d99fc824d","level":"info","message":"received request","hostname":"cdc8a2f93d2f","pid":83}
s3server     | {"name":"S3","bytesSent":233,"clientIP":"::ffff:172.20.0.7","clientPort":49404,"httpMethod":"PUT","httpURL":"/raw-data",**"httpCode":400**,"time":1521306054639,"req_id":"e385aae3c04d99fc824d","elapsed_ms":25.907569,"level":"info","message":"**responded with error XML**","hostname":"cdc8a2f93d2f","pid":83}

We are calling the scality with this boto3 code:

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                        aws_access_key_id='accessKey1',
                        aws_secret_access_key='verySecretKey1',
                        endpoint_url='http://s3server:8000')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id='accessKey1',
                             aws_secret_access_key='verySecretKey1',
                             endpoint_url='http://s3server:8000')

    s3.create_bucket(Bucket='raw-data') # here the exception comes
    bucket = self.s3.Bucket('raw-data')
```

Answer (score 5):

This issue is quite common. In your [config.json](https://github.com/scality/S3/blob/master/config.json#L5) file, which you mount in your Docker container, I assume, there is a restEndpoints section, where you must associate a domain name with a default region. What that means is your frontend domain name should be specified in there, matching a default region.
Do note that that default region does not prevent you from using other regions: it's just where your buckets will be created if you don't specify otherwise.

In the future, I'd recommend you open an issue directly on the [Zenko Forum](https://forum.scality.com), as this is where most of the community and core developers are.

Cheers,

Laure